# How to switch on/off safety mode in embedded(iframe) youtube player?

Tags: iframe, youtube

I use iframe tag to embed YouTube player instead of embedding swf object directly.
There is no problem to watch contents in normal operation, however, specific contents are not playable sometimes. So I tried to check this specific contents in YouTube website on PC.
Same problem happened on the website and I figured out that safety mode was turned on, that's why it was not playable. After I turned off safety mode in website, it worked.

My question is, how to switch on/off safety mode manually in embedded youtube player?